# ngspice not working on mac

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew, x11

I installed ngspice on my mac using homebrew.

```
brew install ngspice --with-x
```

When i run a simple RC Circuit simulation with,

```
*First Circuit

r1 1 2 1k
c1 2 0 1n
v1 1 0 10

.control
tran 1n 10u
plot v(2)
.endc
.end
```

I get this on my terminal

```
******
** ngspice-26 : Circuit level simulation program
** The U. C. Berkeley CAD Group
** Copyright 1985-1994, Regents of the University of California.
** Please get your ngspice manual from http://ngspice.sourceforge.net/docs.html
** Please file your bug-reports at http://ngspice.sourceforge.net/bugrep.html
** Creation Date: Mon Jul 27 21:51:01 IST 2015
******
ngspice 2 -> 
ngspice 2 -> source Ex1.txt 

Circuit: *first circuit

Doing analysis at TEMP = 27.000000 and TNOM = 27.000000


Initial Transient Solution
--------------------------

Node                                   Voltage
----                                   -------
1                                           10
2                                           10
v1#branch                                    0



No. of Data Rows : 10008
Warning: Unable to load any usable fontset
```

And this is on my X11 screen, (unfortunately I can't post images as of now. My X11 plot is just a flat line instead of an exponential).

I am not able to understand how to get rid of this 'Warning: Unable to load any usable fontset' error. I'm pretty sure its related to X11 and not ngspice.

Also when I close my X11 screen directly using 'Cmd + W', I get this error on my terminal,

```
XIO:  fatal IO error 35 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server "/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.pkrxPE5Sf7/org.macosforge.xquartz:0"
      after 493 requests (493 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

And ngspice quits with it.

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the starting conditions for the transient simulation. As ngspice in your case says: Initial transient solution on nodes 1 and 2 is 10 V, and so V(2) will stay there forever.
If you want to have a different initial condition, according to manual chapt. 15.2.2, add a line with .ic to your input file and the uic parameter (use initial condition) to the tran line.

Holger

```
*First Circuit

r1 1 2 1k
c1 2 0 1n
v1 1 0 10

.ic v(2) = 0

.control
tran 1n 10u uic
plot v(2)
.endc
.end
```